# how to do automated testing on both front end and database

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, web-application, database

the testing includes front end GUI testing and database verification and some files verification under windows/linux.

I know that selelnium can be used for front end GUI testing. what about the other testing? what is the proper way to handle those testing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar task in the past. 
In order to have the maximum of flexibility I advice you to you selenium with Java.
At the following address, you will find a example how to start: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted 
As your test will be written in Java, you are free to do all the check you wish in database thx to JDBC or verify if files exist.

Comment: thanks David, the 'GettingStarted' example is helpful. but I could not find examples for database checking and file checking.

Comment: No problem: I found you here a simple example for JDBC connection, it is getting data from database: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm
Then you need to validate what you get from the database in order to make pass or fail your test. You need to complete your script with JUnit or TestNG: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_executing_tests.htm

Answer (score 1):

With selenium you can insert data into database via a frontend and also retrieve and read the reports in a similar way. It also supports file handling as far as I know. Check out documentation on seleniumhq.org and read the manual and functions. I'm sure you will find the code piece you are looking for in there and them use them to build your logic and execute your tests.

Comment: I checked documentation on seleniumhq.org, but I could not find things regarding database and file checking.

Comment: For that you will need to learn about java and the jdbc i suppose. Selenium only allows you to interact with the ui.

Answer (score 0):

Back end testing is as important as front end testing. We had performed database testing with TestingWhiz tool. Please take a look at this webinar video that we conducted on automated database testing - [Webinar Video](http://www.testing-whiz.com/webinar/automated-database-testing-for-web-apps). You can also learn more on database testing with the articles in learn more section.